# Trouble using Guice Persist together with JTA / bitronix

Tags: java, jta, guice-persist, bitronix

We have an existing j2se project that already uses JPA and guice-persist. Now, because we want to add JMS functionality, there is a request for 2-phase-commit and JTA. We'll use the bitronix transaction manager because there's no container (like spring).

To my understanding, the first thing we have to do is to change the transaction-type of the persistence unit from `RESSOURCE-LOCAL` to `JTA`, because we want database transactions to *vote for commit* rather then *commit*. The commit is done on phase 2 after collecting all votes.

With guice-persist we use the `@Transactional` annotation for methods that should run in a single transaction. The `JPAPersistModule` provides an EnitiyManagerFactory and it is used for guice-persist internal classes, like `JpaLocalTxnInterceptor` that wraps the annotated methods.

Now I get exceptions like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1009)
at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:57)
    ...
```

because the `JpaLocalTxnInterceptor` calls `getTransaction()` on the provided entity manager.

I'm quite stuck, at the moment. Is there any way to use guice-persist together with JTA or o we really have to drop guice-persist from the project? Or, is there any replacement for guice-persist if we want to do JTA (with Bitronix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar situation. In our case we were using Guice + Jooq. We wanted Jooq because we have a large legacy Rails DB and wanted fine control plus speed. We picked Guice over Spring because we felt it is a better framework, and it is much faster and we like compile time checking.

We could NOT use Guice persist with Jooq, so we :

- Use Atomikos JTA (free version)
- Wrote our own @Transactional AOP annotation interceptor;
- Our injectable Service provides the java.sql.Connection to our jooq processors, but always supply an Atomikos DataSource bean

We basically modified this code:

http://www.dailyjavatips.com/2011/10/24/database-transactions-google-guice-aop/

So that example uses regular JDBC Tx, but we modified it so it would use Atmomikos' JTA aware Tx instead.

Works like a charm!

Oje

Comment: In my case, we changed the DI framework and use CDI now. Not because of this problem but because there was a decision to migrate everything to a J2EE application (JBoss -> CDI). But writing a custom interceptor for JTA looks like the way to go. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Oje can you provide a repository GIT where it's possible to understand the steps, pleeeese? :)

Comment: @Alexian, that was a corporate private Git account and I was on contract and no longer work there!! The sample in the link above is PRETTY similar to what we had done except that instead of the JDBC connection we use the Atomikos DataSource and call commit/rollback etc on it! Sorry hope that helps!!